# Different DISTINCT behaviour in two similar Databases

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, distinct

I am having two Oracle databases on two separate systems. I copied all data from one to another DB. For the purpose of data analytics I want to measure the quality of my data. I noticed while working that I get different results when I run the same code on my two databases. The COLUMN is my primary-key column.

I want to check the Semantic similarity of this column. So I check for duplicates. Since the COLUMN is the primary key not two identically entires can exist but two entries with different cases are allowed to exist since the database is case sensitiv.

First I run `alter session set NLS_SORT=BINARY_CI` to make the session case insensitiv. Then I run the following code to find duplicates in my Tables.

```
SELECT DISTINCT * 
FROM (SELECT COLUMN COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY COLUMN) AS RN 
      FROM TABLE) 
WHERE RN > 1;
```

At this time I get for both tables following:

```
| COLUMN | RN |
| ------ | -- |
| XXXX   | 2  |
| XXxx   | 2  |
```

Then I set the NLS_COM of both tables to `LINGUSTIC` But get for one table

```
| COLUMN | RN |
| ------ | -- |
| XXXX   | 2  |
| XXxx   | 2  |
```

and for the another one

```
| COLUMN | RN |
| ------ | -- |
| XXxx   | 2  |
```

The `NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS` of both tables are exactly the same. What else should I check to find out why DISTINCT is behaving differently in both systems? What parameters have impact on DISTINCT?

Comment: What is `NR` (column name you show in your output)? The query has `RN`. Did you change the column names from your actual ones? In any case, even if you did that, you should still be consistent. Then: if NR is RN, do you REALLY get a row with RN = 1 when you have the filter RN > 1 in your outer query? Look at your first output, the first row has NR = 1. Then: You don't have a column named `COLUMN`, that's a reserved keyword. If these are all "little mistakes", as I believe they are, I would not be too inclined, personally, to believe much of the other things you are telling us.

Comment: In any case - it wouldn't hurt to check the data also, not just the settings. You say the data is exactly the same; well, check to see if that is indeed true. Take the values that appear to be different (based on your tests so far), and then `select DUMP(column_name) from` the two tables; DUMP shows you exactly, byte by byte, what is stored on disk for each value. Compare them between the two databases; are they really the same?

Comment: RN is Rownumber and its COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY COLUMN)

Comment: My question was, what is NR (column name in your output). Did you mean RN?

Comment: Maybe you forgot to set nls_sort the same way in both sessions? Maybe in the session where your result is only one distinct row you are using a case insensitive sort but the other session is using a case sensitive sort and that's why you got two rows there.

Comment: As I mentioned in the question I check the session parameters in both DBs. They are exactly the same. And I copy the code I run from one window to another so there is no typo or anything happening.

Comment: would the `alter session set NLS_SORT=BINARY_CI` not set both sessions to case insensitiv? Actually without setting them to CI  I will not get any row as result.

Comment: I just realized the DDL-Script somehow didn't create index for the Table which were giving me one row as result. It means the COLUMN wasn't set as primary till now. But I cant explain how it could have impact on it.

Comment: `alter session` would set to case insensitivity, but it does so only for the session you run this statement in. To alter both sessions, you must issue the same command twice - once in each session (in each database). The presence or absence of an index should not affect the result of any query, it should only affect the speed of execution. So that wouldn't be the reason. But if that IS, in fact, different between the two databases... you said they are "identical", and we find more and more things that weren't true in your original question.